# Program works corectly two times after that it goes wrong

Tags: javascript

After entering the correct answer twice, any subsequent try, even if the correct answer is entered again, shows the "try again" output. What is causing this strange behavior?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var answer;
            var firstNum;
            var secondNum;
            var check = true;
            question();

            function question() {
                firstNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
                secondNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
                answer = firstNum * secondNum;
                document.writeln("<h1>How much is " + firstNum + " times " + secondNum + "</h1>");
                document.writeln(answer);
                document.write('<input name="inputAnswer" type="text" id="inputAns"/>');
                document.write('<input name="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Submit Answer" onclick="validate()"/>');
            }

            function validate() {
                if (document.getElementById("inputAns").value == answer) {
                    document.write("Good");
                    check = true;
                    result();
                } else {
                    check = false;
                    document.write("try again");
                    result();
                }
            }

            function result() {
                if (check == true)
                    question();
                else {
                    document.writeln("<h1>How much is " + firstNum + " times " + secondNum + "</h1>");
                    document.writeln(answer);
                    document.write('<input name="inputAnswer" type="text" id="inputAns"/>');
                    document.write('<input name="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Submit Answer" onclick="validate()"/>');
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body></body>

</html>
```

Comment: BTW where are you learning JS from? That's not how most web apps are structured; `document.write` is hardly ever used in practice. It's more common to create elements using `document.createElement` and add behaviour to them using `some_element.addEventListener`.

Comment: @Kos, it sounds like homework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar type of solution but in a different way. try it.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"                                          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
 <h1>How much is <span id="firstnumber"></span>  times <span id="secondnumber"></span></h1>
              answer
                <input name="inputAnswer" type="text" id="inputAns"/>
                <input name="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Submit Answer" onclick="validate()"/>
                <span id="answer"></span>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    var answer;
    var firstNum;
    var secondNum;
    var check= true;
   var count=0;
question();


    function question()
    {   

            firstNum= Math.floor(Math.random()*101);
            secondNum= Math.floor(Math.random()*101);

            answer = firstNum * secondNum;



              document.getElementById("firstnumber").innerHTML=firstNum;
               document.getElementById("secondnumber").innerHTML=secondNum;

    }



    function validate()
    {
        if(document.getElementById("inputAns").value == answer)
        {


            check= true;


        }
        else
        {
            check= false;


        }
        result();


    }

    function result()
    {
        if(check== true)
        {
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML="correct answer"
            count=count+1;


        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML="wrong answer.<br>you've corrected total "+count+" questions.";
        }
        document.getElementById("inputAns").value="";
         question();


    }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you repeatedly create elements with `id="inputAns"`. It isn't allowed for two elements to have the same `id`.

Also note that:

- the output (good / try again) is correct if you type the number in the FIRST input box. That's caused by how `document.getElementByID` works.
- it doesn't matter which "Submit answer" you click - they all do the same thing (`validate()`).